# "Open File in BBEdit" missing from right click menu

Tags: contextual-menu

I have the most recent version of BBEdit installed on my MacBook and iMac, both running the most recent versions of macOS. On my MacBook, when I right click on a file, the menu shows the options to "Search Here in BBEdit" and "Open File in BBEdit" at the very bottom (see image). On my iMac, these options are missing.

How can I get these options on my iMac, too?

[image: screenshot of right click menu]

Comment: Hello Susanne, welcome to Ask Different. I don't use BBEdit but I suppose you have to enable it in System Preferences. Open System Preferences>Keyboard>Shortcuts, select Services, scroll down to Files and Folders and look for the missing entries. Hopefully they will be there and you can simply check them.

Answer (score 1):

As @jaume has explained in their comment, the options can be enabled under System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services > Files and Folders.

Here is a screenshot (as it looks like in German):

[image: screenshot of system preferences]